# How can I pack a thing [e.g. array, object] in JavaScript like in C++?

Tags: javascript, pack

I would like to know how (and if this is possible) to pack arrays in JavaScript like in C++, because I would like to micro-optimise my code by packing an array. In C++ it looks like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
//declarations
#pragma pack(pop)
```

How can I replicate this behaviour in JavaScript?

For knowledge on what packing is, see [this](https://www.joshcaratelli.com/blog/struct-packing).

Comment: What the input and output in c ++ and what you want in Javascript ?

Comment: Can you explain why you think you'd even need this?

Comment: It might be a good idea to describe in words the behavior you want. Prove to the world that you know what `#pragma pack` does. (The C++ code can serve as an example, but lead in with the textual description.) As a side-effect, your question becomes accessible to people who don't know C++; your audience becomes people who know Javascript instead of just those that know Javascript and C++.

Comment: I want to micro-optimise my JavaScript code by packing a array.

Comment: not in a comment, please update your post to talk about what  you're trying to achieve that makes you think you need this because it's almost certainly the case what you want to do can be done, but what you think you need to do to achieve that, can't, and no one likes [an XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) =)

Comment: What is packing? Read this article: https://www.joshcaratelli.com/blog/struct-packing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I'm fairly sure nothing like that exists in JavaScript itself (I know it doesn't in the language specification, and don't think it does in any of the major environments for it). JavaScript has no specified memory format at all for objects or arrays (other than typed arrays, below); implementations do things their own different ways.

You could do it in a browser environment in [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) (Wasm) (with C++ even), but in a standard JavaScript environment you're a bit further removed from the bare metal than that.

For some APIs you might use a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) (like a `Uint8Array`) in order to provide and receive raw bytes/words/longs, but that's really not the same thing as `#pragma pack`.